# Gradient of linear scalar field $X \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AXB)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Could someone explain the following?

$$ \nabla_X \operatorname{tr}(AXB) = BA $$

I understand that

$$ {\rm d} \operatorname{tr}(AXB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA \; {\rm d} X) $$

but I don't quite understand how to move ${\rm d} X$ out of the trace.

Answer (score 13):

The notation is quite misleading (at least for me).

*Hint:*

Does it make sense that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{mn}} \mathop{\rm tr} (A X B) = (B A)_{nm}?$$

*More information:*
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{mn}} \mathop{\rm tr} (A X B) = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{mn}} \sum_{jkl} A_{jk} X_{kl} B_{lj}
= \sum_{jkl} A_{jk} \delta_{km} \delta_{nl} B_{lj}
= \sum_{j} A_{jm} B_{nj} =(B A)_{nm}. $$

Comment: That does make sense if I assume the first equation of $\frac{dtr(AXB)}{dX}$.  But I'm not sure how to get to the first equation using the second equation for $dtr(AXB)$.

Comment: @ChrisD: I added a line explaining how to use my hint.

Comment: I see what you mean by misleading notation.  The resulting matrix is indexed by the transpose of the matrix you differentiate by, $X$.

Therefore, the full matrix solution $BA$ is the transpose of the element by element solution $(BA)_{nm}$. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fabian is there any book that covers it? the Matrix Cookbook does not show the derivations but only the results... so I prefer something else

Comment: I think this is the right notation because the point is that the "derivative with respect to a matrix" is just the usual gradient of a scalar function... which in this very particular case happens to be easily reshaped as a matrix with the same dimensions as $X$.

Answer (score 8):

Try expanding to linear order. This always eases the understanding:

$$\operatorname{tr}(A (X+dX)B)=A_{ij} (X_{jk}+dX_{jk})B_{ki}$$

where Einstein's summation rule is used. Substracting $\operatorname{tr}(AXB)$ you get

$$\begin{align}
d\operatorname{tr}(AXB)&=\operatorname{tr}(A(X+dX)B)-\operatorname{tr}(AXB)\\&=A_{ij} dX_{jk}B_{ki}=\underbrace{B_{ki}A_{ij}}_{=(BA)_{kj}} \; dX_{jk}
\end{align}$$

Comment: When you say 'expanding to linear order', do you mean write out the actual matrix element summations?

I had to do that manually to prove $$\operatorname{tr}(A (X+dX)B)=A_{ij} (X_{jk}+dX_{jk})B_{ki})$$ to myself.  Is that something that's easily derived without explicitly expanding the matrices or is this something people generally just memorize about traces?

Comment: What I meant was writing $X+dX$ and work with that, keeping only stuff that is linear in $dX$. In this case, everything was linear to begin with, so my comment was a bit misleading. But it is the right  way to work when deriving more complicated tensorial derivatives like, say, $$\frac{\partial \det (A)}{\partial A}=\det(A) \left(A^{-1}\right)^T$$

Answer (score 8):

These are the main equations to remember:

1. Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}}\text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX}) = \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}}\text{Tr}(\mathbf{XA}) = \mathbf{A}^T
\end{equation}

2. Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Then

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}}\text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX^T}) = \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}}\text{Tr}(\mathbf{X^TA}) = \mathbf{A}
\end{equation}

**Proof 1**.

\begin{equation}
\left[ \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX}) \right]_{i,j} = \frac{d}{dx_{i,j}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX}) = \frac{d}{dx_{i,j}} \sum_{k,l} a_{k,l} x_{l,k} = a_{j,i} = \left[\mathbf{A}^T\right]_{i,j}
\end{equation}

**Proof 2**

\begin{equation}
\left[ \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX^T}) \right]_{i,j} = \frac{d}{dx_{i,j}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{AX^T}) = \frac{d}{dx_{i,j}} \sum_{k,l} a_{k,l} x_{k,l} = a_{i,j} = \left[\mathbf{A}\right]_{i,j}
\end{equation}

Once you have these, you can derivate crazy things like the following:

**Example 1.** Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}) = (\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^T) \mathbf{X}
\end{equation}

We can derive it as follows:

\begin{split}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}) =& \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}) + \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{Y})\\
    =& \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} + (\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A})^T\\
    =& \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} = (\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^T) \mathbf{X}
\end{split}

**Example 2.** Consider now this example.

\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{X}) = \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C})
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} f(\mathbf{X}) =& \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C})\\
    +& \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C})\\
    +& \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{C})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Calculating these:

\begin{split}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C}
\end{split}

\begin{split}
    \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C}) =& \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A})\\
    =& (\mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A})^T\\
    =& \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{C}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}^T
\end{split}

\begin{split}
   \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{C}) = \frac{d}{d\mathbf{Y}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}
\end{split}

So the result is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{C} + \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{C}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}^T + \mathbf{C} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are correct, but I feel like they missed the point.
Arguments that take a basis to prove a result independent of bases should be approached with caution.

---

First of all, according to the Matrix Cookbook, the formula is
$$ \frac{d\mathrm{tr}(AXB)}{dX} = (BA)^T,$$
not the one given in your question.

What's confusing about this presentation is that
$f (X) = \mathrm{tr}(AXB)$
is a linear map, so it's derivative (=linear approximation) is itself.

So in fact, the statement should read
$$ f(X) = \mathrm{tr}(AXB) = (BA)^T,$$
which is clearly wrong.

But consider the Frobenius inner product on $\mathrm{Mat}(m, n)$. For $U, V \in \mathrm{Mat}(m, n)$:

$$\langle U, V \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(U^T V).$$

By the Riesz representation theorem, $f$ can be represented as

$$f(X) = \langle U, X \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(U^TX).$$

for a fixed $U \in \mathrm{Mat}(m, n)$.

Clearly $U = (BA)^T$ does the job, so the more precise statement is

$$\mathrm{tr}(AXB) = \langle (BA)^T, X \rangle,$$

which is a triviality.