# Confused about chain rule in Frechet derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule, frechet-derivative

I've recently started to learn about Frechet derivatives and now have a simple example which I'm not sure if I've solved correctly. To be honest, I've only got a poor understanding of how it works so please assume I am starting at zero. Given $\delta = \sum_i \lambda_iX_i$ for some matrices $X_i$ and real numbers $\lambda_i$ and $N(X)$ being a linear transformation on $X$, find the Frechet derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_l}Tr(A\log(N(\delta)),$$

for some $l$.

---

Redoing my attempted solution after reading greg's answer. Would appreciate if anyone can comment on the correctness of it!

We have
\begin{align}
d Tr(A\log(N(\delta)) &= Tr(dA\log(N(\delta)) \\
&= Tr\left(\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}\right)dN(\delta)\right) \\
&= Tr\left(\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}\right)N(d\delta)\right) \\
&= Tr\left(\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}\right)N(X_k d\lambda_k)\right) \\
\end{align}

I have used the fact that $Tr$ and $N()$ are both linear operators and the solution posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3147270/99503) to write the function $d\ (A\log X)$. I believe that this cannot proceed further unless I can say something about $N()$ to rewrite $N(X_k d\lambda_k)$ as $ M(X_k) d\lambda_k$. If and only if I could do that step, then I have

\begin{align}
d Tr(A\log(N(\delta)) &= Tr\left(\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}\right)M(X_k) d\lambda_k\right)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda_k}Tr(A\log(N(\delta)) &= \left(\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tN(\delta)}\right)M(X_k)\right)^T
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \sum_{i=k}^N \lambda_kX_k = \lambda_kX_k \cr
}$$
where the expression on the far RHS uses the index summation convention.

Now calculate the differential and derivative for the trace of a simple nonlinear function.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}\Big(Y^3\Big) \cr
d\phi
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(3Y^2\,dY\Big) = {\rm Tr}\Big(3Y^2X_k\,d\lambda_k\Big) \cr
\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda_k} &= {\rm Tr}\Big(3Y^2X_k\Big) \cr
}$$
A general function $f(Y)$ follows the same pattern.
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= {\rm Tr}\Big(f(Y)\Big) \cr
\frac{d\psi}{d\lambda_k} &= {\rm Tr}\Big(f'(Y)\,X_k\Big) \cr
}$$
where $f'$ denotes the ordinary derivative of the function.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Using this and your comments on my other question, I've redone the solution. I believe it can only proceed if I make an assumption about $N()$, as I have clarified in the edited question. If you wouldn't mind taking a moment to read it, can I check that this is the correct solution to the original problem I posed?

Comment: It looks correct, I'm just not sure how _practical_ it will prove to be. Evaluating an improper integral of a matrix-valued function is extremely tricky. If you just need a closed-form result, is an integral expression more useful than the original derivative expression?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Thanks for the help :)