# Does this identity involving integral of matrix logs/exponentials hold?

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3147270/610522), makes the claim that for matrices $A$ and $X$, where $X$ is positive definite Hermitian,

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+tX}A\mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{1+tX}=\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\int_0^1\mathrm{d}s \mathrm{e}^{-stX}A\mathrm{e}^{stX}\mathrm{e}^{-tX}\text{.}
$$

However, I don't think this is true. I worked out the Taylor expansion of both expressions and carried out the integral over $s$, the results seem to differ by multiplicative factor in each terms of the series sum.

Comment: $X$ is assumed positive definite and Hermitian, right?

Comment: Yep, that's a fair assumption, will add to question

Comment: Update: it doesn't hold, I checked for a basic case.