# Differentiating D-trace Loss - differentiating inner products

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I was going through this paper which tries to estimate the difference between precision matrices of gaussian graph models - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09188.pdf.
They define a loss function (D-trace loss function) as follows

$L_D(\Delta, \Sigma_X, \Sigma_Y) = \dfrac14(\langle\Sigma_X \Delta, \Delta\Sigma_Y\rangle+\langle\Sigma_Y\Delta,\Delta\Sigma_X\rangle) - \langle\Delta, \Sigma_X-\Sigma_Y\rangle$

And the first derivative with respect to $\Delta$ is given by

$(\Sigma_X\Delta\Sigma_Y+\Sigma_Y\Delta\Sigma_X)/2 - (\Sigma_X-\Sigma_Y)$

How does one obtain the first derivative of the loss function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the answers in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118792/derivative-of-a-trace-with-respect-to-a-matrix and just use the regular product rule.

Comment: Was able to solve the problem with the help of the answer. Thanks :)