# Does there exist a minimal matrix with an analog to single-variable calculus?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Given square matrices $A, B, C$, let's say we have a function of the form $X \mapsto AX^2 + BX + C$. Is it possible to "optimize" this matrix in any sense, by computing the class of matrices for which the derivative with respect to $X$ has a matrix-norm of $0$, similar to how you'd compute the extrema of the single-variable case $x \mapsto ax^2 + bx + c$? Is there any analog of matrix-valued calculus like this?

Comment: Are you asking if, for example, we can find a matrix $D$ such that $DY = 2AX + B$?

Comment: It would be easier if the input were a matrix but the output were a scalar. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118792/339790).

Comment: @Dan If that is indeed the correct interpretation of a derivative with respect to a matrix, then yes.